# Getting the sub-class type

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 3 classes:

```
class O
{
}

class A : O
{
}

class B : A
{
}
```

When I call my code:

```
List<O> myList = new List<O>();
myList.Add(new A());
myList.Add(new B());

foreach (O obj in myList)
{
    if (obj is A)
    {
         // do something
    }
    else if (obj is B)
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

However I realized that `if (obj is A)` will be evaluated to be `true` even when my `obj` is of `class B`. Is there a way to write the statement such that it evaluates to true if and only if `obj` is of `class B`?

Comment: `obj.GetType() == typeof(B)`

Comment: Just a thought exercise, reorder your conditionals. Most specific to least specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two method `GetType` and `typeof`

> GetType is a method on object. It provides a Type object, one that
>   indicates the most derived type of the object instance.

and

> Typeof returns Type objects. It is often used as a parameter or as a
>   variable or field. The typeof operator is part of an expression that
>   acquires the Type pointer for a class or value type

Try like this

```
 if(obj.GetType() == typeof(A)) // do something
 else if(obj.GetType() == typeof(B)) //do something
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you define a virtual function in the base class and override it in the derived types, doing what you need in the different cases?

```
class O {
    public virtual void DoSomething() {
        // do smtgh in the 'O' case
    }
}

class A : O {
    public override void DoSomething() {
        // do smtgh in the 'A' case
    }
}

class B : A {
    public override void DoSomething() {
        // do smtgh in the 'B' case
    }
}
```

Then your loop becomes

```
foreach (O obj in myList) {
    obj.DoSomething();
}
```